# Grafana table with AWS CloudWatch metric

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, grafana

I am trying to create a table in Grafana, which should look like this:

```
BUCKET         CURRENT    MIN        AVG        MAX
my-bucket-1    22 GB      0 GB       0.2 GB     22 GB
my-bucket-2    200 KB     200 KB     200 KB     200 KB
my-bucket-3    ...        ...        ...        ...
```

... and I fail miserably. And I think I am completely clueless. I would appreciate any help here, I really don't get how this works.

What I *have*, is this:

[image: grafana-config-metrics]

[image: grafana-config-options]

What I *get* from this (which does not remotely look like what I want) is this:

[image: grafana-table-result]

(and this is also the only line in the table).

Appreciate any help ... thanks!

Comment: I assume you looked at the official doc beforehand: http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/cloudwatch/?

Comment: you assume correct. (and the email notification of this comment arrived just now - 16 days later). still didn't succeed btw :/

Comment: @flypenguin can you add your screenshots directly?